# When slack lining between trees, how big should the tree trunk be if the line is 15 meters, person is ~150 pounds?

Tags: safety, safety-standards, slacklining

[When slacklining between trees, how big should the tree trunks be?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20062/when-slacklining-between-trees-how-big-should-the-tree-trunks-be)

Followup question:

I'm writing to ask how big the tree trunks should be exactly if I only have a 15meter line and I'm only walking on it or learning how to slack-line and not doing tricks. I weigh around 150ib.

Polyester line, 2inches wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My son slack lines (6' & 165lbs) on +15 M of 1". Using tree savers and each tree is about 6 to 8 in in diameter. He practices on a staked rigging over 6" rounds that lie on their side at each end of the run. Line is permanently mounted and staked into the ground. So when newbies or his mom gets a wild hair and tries it, they don't bust themselves up.

Comment: does using a thicker line require more diameters?

Comment: what's rigging?

Comment: Can you shorten the line or is it just 15 meters?